# Will buying a fit meter allow all of us to use Wii Fit U for free?

Tags: wii-fit-u, fit-meter

Nintendo has a promotion about Wii fit U, which says you get Wii Fit U for free if you had a balance board, and you buy a Fit Meter, but I can't tell if that means that I get the game for the whole family, or if that's just for my one account. I can't find anything definitive one way or the other, and I don't want to buy more than I need to to keep my whole family playing.

http://wiifitu.nintendo.com/free-trial/

Comment: That promotion ended almost 3 weeks before you even asked the question. There isn't really any answer, because the premise of the question isn't true anymore - and was never true while this question existed.

Comment: I don't think that's true. I had to download the game before that point, and I did, now if I want to keep playing, I need a Fit Meter?

Answer (score 3):

Once you download Wii Fit U and it is activated, any account on your Wii U can use it. The Wii Fit Meter will only be usable on one account, but a Wii Fit Meter is not necessary for each individual to use the game.

I did this and share the game with my wife. I gave the Wii Fit Meter to her, but I can play the game on my account and she can play on her account as well.